# SwiftUI: Get circle collision

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, montecarlo

Hi I am playing around with app that uses Monte Carlo Approximation Of Pi. So I wrote code that create square, circle inside and function that generate random dots. But I am stuck on getting information on when little circle is inside of the big one.

This is my code:

```
struct Drop: Hashable {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
}

let size = 300.0

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var num = 0
    @State var drops: [Drop] = []
    @State var timerIsOn = false
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                mainContent()
                ForEach(drops.indices, id:\.self) { idx in
                    drop(dot: drops[idx])
                        .blendMode(.difference)
                }
            }.frame(width: size, height: size)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if self.timerIsOn {
                        createDot()
                    }
                }
                
            settings()
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }

    func createDot() {
        let randomX = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size)
        let randomY = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size)
        
        drops.append(Drop(x: randomX, y: randomY))
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func mainContent() -> some View {
        ZStack{
            Circle()
            Circle()
                .stroke()
            Rectangle()
                .stroke()
        }
    }
    func drop(dot: Drop) -> some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
            .position(x: dot.x, y: dot.y)
    }
    func settings() -> some View {
        HStack{
            Button {
                timerIsOn.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Start")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to determine if "...little circle is inside of the big one...".
The following example code is a basic approach using the big circle `path`: (note you will need to check the math and path setup)

```
struct Drop: Hashable {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var isInside: Bool  // <--- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // --- here
    let size = 300.0
    let bigCircle = Circle()
    @State var path = Path()

    @State var num = 0
    @State var drops: [Drop] = []
    @State var timerIsOn = false
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                mainContent()
                ForEach(drops.indices, id:\.self) { idx in
                    drop(dot: drops[idx])
                        .blendMode(.difference)
                }
            }.frame(width: size, height: size)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if self.timerIsOn {
                        createDot()
                    }
                }
            
            settings()
            results().padding()  // <--- here
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            // --- here
            path = bigCircle.path(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size, height: size)))
        }
    }
    
    func createDot() {
        let randomX = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size)
        let randomY = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size)
        // --- here
        let isIn = path.contains(CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY))
        drops.append(Drop(x: randomX, y: randomY, isInside: isIn)) 
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func mainContent() -> some View {
        ZStack{
            bigCircle  // <--- here
            Circle().stroke()
            Rectangle().stroke()
        }
    }
    
    func drop(dot: Drop) -> some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
            .position(x: dot.x, y: dot.y)
    }
    
    func settings() -> some View {
        HStack{
            Button {
                timerIsOn.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text(timerIsOn ? "Stop" : "Start") // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
    
    // --- here
    func results() -> some View {
        let ins = Double(drops.filter{$0.isInside}.count)
        let total = Double(drops.count)
        return Text(total <= 0.0 ? "0" : "\(ins / total * 4.0)")
    }
    
}
```